Rendering on command line not matching GUI
I have Blender 4.2.3 LTS installed on MacOS and Linux. I am trying to render https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/demo/geometry-nodes/index_of_nearest.blend file. It works fine when rendered through GUI.
But when rendered through CLI, using blender -b index_of_nearest.blend  -o output_ -F FFMPEG -a, the rendering is completely different with no movement of the particles at all.
I have tried various options explicitly setting -E to BLENDER_EEVEE_NEXT or CYCLES on MacOS and setting the scene name with -S but the result is same. I have even tried rendering from Linux command line and the result is same. The rendering on Linux using command line matches with rendering on MacOS with command line.
Is there a way to dump equivalent command line rendering options when rendered through GUI. I ran with --debug-all and I didn't see anything obvious.
It looks like I am missing some command line option and any help is appreciated.

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

I included the blend file URL in the original post but here is it uploaded as suggested. https://blend-exchange.com/b/OJ0gbORl/
